# How can set UITableVewCell's accessibility traits to be 'link' only?

Tags: ios, accessibility, voiceover

I have a `UITableViewCell` that is displayed with a discolor indicator but opens another application rather than pushing a view controller (for example 'Visit our Website', opening in Safari). My limited understanding of accessibility and voiceover leads me to believe this should be marked as a 'link' rather than a 'button', since the user will be leaving the app. To accomplish this I set the `accessibilityTraits` to `.link`.

However, as soon as I set the disclosure indicator on the cell, the cell is read as 'Visit our Website - button, link".

Is there a way to keep the disclosure indicator but remove the `.button` trait from a cell?

Comment: Did you debug **Trait** value in **Object Inspector** whether related view/cell's traits are set to `.link` only or both, using *Debug View Hierarchy*?

Comment: I checked in the Accessibility Inspector and the traits are `.link`, `.button`, and `.staticText` (although `.statictext` doesn't get read out to the user so isn't an issue).

Comment: Can you share related piece of your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to keep the disclosure indicator but remove the .button trait from a cell?

One way to reach your goal is to **create a `UITableViewCell` subclass** with the `.link` value as `accessibilityTraits` property.

```
class testCell:UITableViewCell {

    override var accessibilityTraits: UIAccessibilityTraits {
        get { return .link }
        set {  }
    }
}
```

Indicating this new cell type in your view controller will read out only its link property as follows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
                        cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> testCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "reuseIdentifier", 
                                             for: indexPath) as! testCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Visit our Website"
    return cell
}
```

Following this rationale, **you can set UITableVewCell's accessibility traits to be 'link' only**.

If need be, there's a [captivating website](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#element-trait) where many informations about the traits are available with illustrations and code snippets.